# Como fazer duas consultas usando o mesmo MySqlConnection?

Tags: c#, mysql, otimização

Eu tenho o seguinte trecho de código:

```cs
using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(conexao)){
    try
    {
        string consulta = "SELECT * FROM tb_Cliente WHERE ID_Cliente IN ("+listaClientes+")";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(consulta,conn);
        conn.Open();
        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            using(MySqlConnection conn2 = new MySqlConnection(conexao))
            {
                try
                {
                    consulta = "INSERT INTO tb_Teste (ID_Cliente,Nome_Cliente,Idade_Cliente,Data_Insert) VALUES (@ID_Cli,@Nome_Cli,@Idade_Cli,@Data_insert)";
                    MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(consulta,conn2);
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_Cli",reader["ID_Cliente"]);
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nome_Cli",reader["Nome_Cliente"]);
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_Cli",reader["ID_Cliente"]);
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Idade_Cli",reader["Idade_Cliente"]);
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data_insert",DateTime.Now);
                    conn2.Open();
                    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conn2.Close();
                }
                catch(MySqlException ex)
                {
                    EscreverLog("ERRO: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(MySqlException ex)
    {
        EscreverLog("ERRO: " + ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Nele eu faço um SELECT buscando todos os clientes no range especificado pela string listaClientes e para cada resultado eu faço um INSERT em outra tabela, com outras informações a mais.

Rodando o código tudo funciona normal mas eu acho que é errado abrir várias MySqlConnection e MySqlCommands. Como eu posso alterar o código para que ele fique menos "bagunçado"? Por exemplo usando a mesma conexão ou até mesmo o mesmo Command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não precisa usar outras connections, basta usar a mesma, o que precisa é mudar o command ou criar outro, e aqui não há problema, porque cada Command é uma operação diferente:

```
using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(conexao)){
    try
    {
        string consulta = "SELECT * FROM tb_Cliente WHERE ID_Cliente IN ("+listaClientes+")";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(consulta,conn);
        conn.Open();
        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(consulta,conn);

        while(reader.Read())
        {
            consulta = "INSERT INTO tb_Teste (ID_Cliente,Nome_Cliente,Idade_Cliente,Data_Insert) VALUES (@ID_Cli,@Nome_Cli,@Idade_Cli,@Data_insert)";
            cmd2.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_Cli",reader["ID_Cliente"]);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nome_Cli",reader["Nome_Cliente"]);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_Cli",reader["ID_Cliente"]);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Idade_Cli",reader["Idade_Cliente"]);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data_insert",DateTime.Now);
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    catch(MySqlException ex)
    {
        EscreverLog("ERRO: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Note que, pode compartilhar a mesma `Connection`, que é fechado ao sair do bloco `using`.

Isso é pessoal, mas eu prefiro colocar o `using` dentro do `try`:

```
 try
 {
    using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(conexao)){
    }
 }
```

Isso porque dessa forma, também vai tratar um erro ao criar a Connection, no seu exemplo só trata os erros após abrir a Connection.

Ainda sobre connections, uma boa ideia é criar um *Pool* de conections que permanecem abertas por um certo tempo, então ai usar o `new MySqlConnection(conexao)` uma conexão que já existe e aberta será usado, claro se for **as mesmas credenciais**.

Pode ler mais sobre isso aqui: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connections-string.html

Comment: Dentro do while é recomendado ter um try/catch? Ou se ocorrer um erro lá dentro ele cai no catch de fora?

Comment: isso depende se quer tratar algo específico dentro do `while`. Imagina que não tenha um `try/catch` dentro do `while`, se der um erro em qualquer insert, vai sair do código e cair no "catch de fora" como você chamou. Só faria sentido ter um `try/catch` dentro do `while` se quiser por exemplo tratar um erro dentro do `while`, por exemplo se um `insert` falhar, tratar isso e tentar fazer o próximo :)

Comment: No meu caso o `catch` está sendo usado somente para popular o log de erros em consultas, e como o while faz um novo INSERT acho que vou manter um `try/catch` dentro dele.

Comment: Eu ainda esta a editar  pergunta, mas entendi o seu ponto, eu só mudaria o primeiro `try` para antes do `using`, veja o que comentei na pergunta :)

Comment: Acebei de testar a sua solução e ocorre um erro ao tentar usar a mesma conexão que ja possui um DataReader aberto nela.

Comment: você precisa ter `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` na sua connection string para fazer isso, como não colocou na pergunta pensei que tinha isso já. Isso pode não funcionar com packages mais antigos. Acho que também da pra alterar no código, mas não tenho certeza

Comment: quem negativou pode explicar qual o problema com a resposta?

Comment: não foi eu deixar bem claro, mas, dentro do `reader` não precisa instanciar novamente o MySqlCommand!

Comment: @novic não tenho certeza, pq o commnad ainda está sendo usado, o `Reader` não faz fetch de todo o resultado de uma vez, mas a cada `Read()`, acho não vai funcionar usando o mesmo Command, não vejo problema em criar um novo

Comment: Eu estou dizendo recriar novamente MySqlCommand, você só precisa em cada loop do `read()` altere os `Paramenters`. Em cada loop do `Reader()` é lido um linha por vez!

Comment: ah agora percebi esse detalhe, bem observado @novic vou editar e por essa melhoria :)

Answer (score 1):

Deve sim utilizar a mesma conexão, não é um bom negócio ficar abrindo várias conexões para a mesma situação, então um exemplo minimo, mas, com resalvas:

- O que seria: `listaClientes`, exemplifique?
- Presta atenção na parte de adicionar paramentos sempre colocando um `clear`!
- Tomar cuidado com `reader` já aberto, após utilizar dar um `Close()` ou um `Dispose()` (a segunda é a melhor forma, para logo liberar esse recurso quando assim não fizer sentido existir).

Um código básico, servindo de exemplo minimo:

Primeiro crie o modelo para receber os valores da outra tabela e utilize o `DataReader` e utilize o método `Dispose` (`using` já resolve como demonstrado no exemplo, o mesmo método é chamado ao final dessa chave do `using`). Com esses dados preparados utilize a estrutura `foreach` e passe o valor para a nova tabela, exemplo:

---

```
public class Ex 
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Nome {get;set;}
    public int Idade {get;set;}
    public DateTime DataAdd {get;set;} = DateTime.Now;
}
static void Example()
{
    string conexao = "";
    string listaClientes = "";
    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(conexao))
    {
        conn.Open();
        try
        {
            string consulta = " SELECT * FROM tb_Cliente WHERE ID_Cliente IN  ";
            consulta += " (" + listaClientes + ") ";
            List<Ex> listEx = neew List<Ex>();
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(consulta, conn))
            {
                using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    consulta = " INSERT INTO tb_Teste (ID_Cliente,Nome_Cliente,Idade_Cliente,Data_Insert) ";
                    consulta += " VALUES (@ID_Cli,@Nome_Cli,@Idade_Cli,@Data_insert)";
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            listEx.add(new Ex {
                                Id = reader.GetInt32(0),
                                Nome = reader.getString(1),
                                Idade = reader.getInt32(2)                              
                            });
                        }
                        catch (MySqlException ex)
                        {
                            //EscreverLog("ERRO: " + ex.Message);
                        }
                    }                   
                }
            }
            
            using (MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(consulta, conn))
            {
                foreach(var e in listEx)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        cmd2.Parameters.Clear();                                        
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_Cli", e.Id);
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nome_Cli", e.Nome);
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_Cli", e.Id);
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Idade_Cli", e.Idade);
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data_insert", e.DataAdd);
                        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (MySqlException ex)
                    {
                        //EscreverLog("ERRO: " + ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            //EscreverLog("ERRO: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Existe a forma de transferir informações de uma tabela para outra sem precisa fazer `for`, `loop`, criar estruturas, ou seja, diretamente na SQL

```
static void SQL()
{
  StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
  str.Append(" INSERT INTO tb_Teste (ID_Cliente,Nome_Cliente,Idade_Cliente,Data_Insert) ");
  str.Append(" SELECT ID_Cliente,Nome_Cliente,Idade_Cliente,Data_Insert FROM tb_Cliente ");
  str.Append(" WHERE ID_Cliente IN(" + listaClientes + ")");
  using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(conexaoStr))
  using (MySqlCommand command1 = new MySqlCommand(str.ToString(), conn))
  {
    conn.Open();
    command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
```

seria uma forma prática de passar valores entre tabelas.

Comment: `listaCliente` é apenas uma string com os ids dos clientes, por exemplo: se o listaClientes = "1,3,5", o SELECT busca somente os clientes com ids IN 1,3,5. 
Obrigado pela dica do Clear().